# Deleting data using Stored Procedure in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm Have a Problem in deleting my data in my database. When I Click the delete button, There's an error pop out saying that **Unable to cast of Type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' to type 'System.IConvertible'.** Can anyone solve this? its my first time to encounter this error.

The code below is calling the **stored Procedure** in my Database.

Here's the code I use

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlParameter[] pms = new MySqlParameter[1];
        pms[0] = new MySqlParameter("uProdNo", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        pms[0].Value = ProdNo;

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conString;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "pos_delete";

        command.Parameters.AddRange(pms);

        conString.Open();
        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            dt.Rows.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry nothing to be deleted");
        }
        conString.Close();

    }
```

Comment: probably a typo: it should be `ProdNo.Text`, converted to a number

Comment: @dlatikay Thank you

Answer (score 0):

How can you assign a textbox to an integer parameter?

Provide as `Convert.ToInt32(ProdNo.Text)`

Answer (score 0):

You should use converter `Convert.ToInt32(ProdNo.Text)` if not work use this `Convert.ToDecimal(ProdNo.Text)`

So, The final code will be

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        MySqlParameter[] pms = new MySqlParameter[1];
        pms[0] = new MySqlParameter("uProdNo", MySqlDbType.Int32);
        pms[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(ProdNo.Text);

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand();

        command.Connection = conString;
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "pos_delete";

        command.Parameters.AddRange(pms);

        conString.Open();
        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
        {
            dt.Rows.Clear();
            MessageBox.Show("Deleted");

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry nothing to be deleted");
        }
        conString.Close();

    }
```